# Install php-cgi on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to install php-cgi on Mac OS X Yosemite keeping the standard PHP version provided by the OS?

Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: Use a tool like Homebrew.

Comment: Yes I've tried with Homebrew, but I only found solutions where you have to change the PHP version of the system. Like: 
`brew tap homebrew/dupes`
`brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php`
`brew install php54`

Comment: What does that mean, "change the PHP version of the system"? Homebrew doesn't "change the PHP version of the system".

Comment: The solution I've found requires to install PHP 5.4, changing the default PHP system version, which is 5.5 for Yosemite. I would like to keep the default version, and just install the php-cgi module. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you use vagrant or something like that? I like to keep my OS fresh.

Comment: I know. But I need to quickly compile some PHP to HTML to create static templates (through Grunt task on watch). Passing through Vagrant (and nfs) is just too slow, so I wanted to make them locally.

Comment: If you mean that typing `php` on the command line resolves to Homebrew's PHP instead of OS X's PHP, that's simply because `/usr/local/bin` has a higher priority in your PATH than `/usr/bin`. They're still both there.

Comment: Yes, correct. I just wondered if it was possible not to install another PHP version, keep the one already installed on OS X and add the php-cgi module to it, like you would do for example in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install php5-cgi`

Comment: It's probably possible, yes. However, you may have to do a lot more manual work, and it may all be for naught with the next OS X update. I'd leave the system PHP as is and use Homebrew installations which you can keep updated and customised on your own terms.

Comment: Ok, looks like it's easier to manage a different version than a single module. I will take this solution. Thanks deceze.

Answer (score 11):

You can install PHP easily with Homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php

brew install php54
```

Homebrew doesn't change the version of the system PHP. System and Homebrew versions are located in different directories. This is how it looks like for me:

System `/usr/bin/php`:

```
/usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29)
```

Homebrew `/usr/local/bin/php`:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Nov 14 2014 10:30:28)
```

Comment: Thanks Gergo. Yes, that's the solution I've found. I just wondered if it was possible not to install another PHP version, keep the one already installed on OS X and add the php-cgi module to it, like you would do for example in Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install php5-cgi`

Comment: Don't think it's possible to install only `php-cgi` with Homebrew. Does the Homebrew installation cause any issues?

Comment: I thought there was an easy way to install just the module, without altering too much the standard system...but it looks like it's better with your solution, so I will stick with it. Thanks.

Comment: there get `Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use PHP CGI on Mac OS X you will need PHP build with the CGI enabled. By default, PHP version 4.3 and higher is built with "-enable-cli" option so default interface is CLI (Command Line Interface). You can check this by running "php -v" from the shell. Output will probably be something like this:

PHP 4.4.4 (cli) ....
CLI does not output any headers and output is plain text by default. More details about this is available here.

In order to use PHP with the wxWebServer (or any other CGI application), you will need to build your own PHP binaries with CGI SAPI. It's simple, it takes only 15 minutes and you will be proud of yourself for having a "personal" build of the PHP. Here is the procedure, step by step:

Download the complete source code for the latest PHP version from php.net. Instructions here are for PHP 5.2.3 but should work for PHP 4 as well. I tested with 4.4.7 too.

Unpack downloaded archive somewhere, for example ~/Temp/php-5.2.3

Open terminal window (shell) and go to folder where you unpacked files:

```
cd ~/Temp/php-5.2.3
```

Decide where you want to install this custom PHP build and create folder. This document will assume it's custom folder under your home folder, for example if user name is webdev it's /Users/webdev/custom/php5

Create that folder (in Finder or in Terminal with "mkdir ~/custom; mkdir ~/custom/php5")
Go back to that Terminal window, you should still be in ~/Temp/php-5.2.3.
Run ./configure with CLI disabled if you are planning to use this private PHP build only for CGI. Modify paths and options to reflect your preferences.
You don't need option "--disable-cli", you can replace it with "--enable-cli" if you plan to use this PHP for something more. You will get both binaries but you will need to use php-cgi in wxWebServer.
Here is a full command line for .configure that should produce PHP with all common options and CLI disabled:

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/webdev/custom/php5 --disable-cli --enable-cgi --enable-trans-sid
  --enable-mbstring --with-xml --enable-exif --enable-mbregex --enable-dbx --enable-sockets
  --with-iodbc=/usr --with-curl=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --sysconfdir=/private/etc
  --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --without-pear
```

When configure is completed, run

```
  make install
```

Edit your profile (~/.profile) to add new php path before existing one. Add something like this to the end of your .profile file:

```
PATH=~/custom/php5/bin:$PATH

export PATH
```

If you don't know how to edit profile from the command line, just create a plain text file in TextEdit containing those 2 lines and save it in your home folder (~/Users/webdev) as newpath.txt. Then open Terminal and enter command:

```
cat newpath.txt >> .profile
```

The easiest way for changes to take effect is to log out and log back in (or you can use source command).
Congratulations, you now have a custom php installation! If you wish to use other PHP just comment your changes to .profile

Verify your new PHP is the default one:

```
# which php-cgi
```

/Users/webdev/custom/php5/bin/php-cgi

## php-cgi -v

PHP 5.2.3 (cgi) (built: Jul 11 2007 00:48:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies

If you wish, you may now delete the source files in ~/Temp/php-5.2.3. To remove you custom PHP just delete target folder, i.e.

```
"/Users/webdev/custom/php4".
```

Once you have custom php installation, configure wxWebServer to use new php binaries. Regardless if you enabled or disabled CLI, you can use php-cgi (output of "which php-cgi", in this case
"/Users/webdev/custom/php5/bin/php-cgi").
If you disabled CLI build, you may also use php binary as it will be CGI build. That's it, enjoy your personal PHP build!

[Found It Here](http://www.senkas.com/wxwebserver/mac-php-cgi.php)